# How to deal with pagination in a reactive Quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus

I'm a bit stuck trying to build a reactive application using Quarkus. Specifically, I'm using reactive routes, panache reactive and hibernate with PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to implement pagination in my application. Exposing a resource which returns a findAll() or listAll(), I'd like to return a PaginatedResponse and to do so I tried to combine 2 unis (one for the list of entities and another one to get the amount of elements), but I'm getting a well known error because of "[HR000068: This method should exclusiverly be invoked from a Vert.x EventLoop thread](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/#_sessions_and_vert_x_contexts)".

I didn't find a clear example about how to deal with this use case. So, how can I deal with pagination in a reactive application? How can I manage the session manually to do so (return the listAll() and the count())?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to @Davide D'Alto for your help.

Finally, I run one query for the count and then chain the entities as is given  below:

```java
@Singleton
@RouteBase(path = "/v1", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public class OrderResource {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OrderResource.class.getName());

    @Inject
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Route(path = "/orders", methods = HttpMethod.GET)
    @WithSession
    public Uni<PaginatedResponse<List<OrderResponse>>> orders() {
        log.trace("OrderResource.orders()");

        return orderRepository.count().chain(count -> {
            return orderRepository.listAll().onItem().ifNotNull().transform(entities -> {
                List<OrderResponse> res = new ArrayList<>();
                for (OrderEntity e : entities) {
                    int status = 0;
                    if (e.status == OrderStatus.COMPLETED)
                        status = 1;
                    List<OrderItemResponse> resItems = e.orderItemEntities.stream().map(item -> new OrderItemResponse(item.productId, item.price)).toList();
                    res.add(new OrderResponse(e.id, e.uuid, status, resItems, e.price, e.createdAt, e.updatedAt));
                }
                return new PaginatedResponse<List<OrderResponse>>(count, res);
            });
        });
    }
    
}
```

Further information [here](https://gist.github.com/serrodcal/bf70923208d0b589364850d95d27337a)

Answer (score 1):

There is a paragraph with all the methods available in Panache for pagination:
https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache#paging

Here's the examples:

```java
// create a query for all living persons
PanacheQuery<Person> livingPersons = Person.find("status", Status.Alive);

// make it use pages of 25 entries at a time
livingPersons.page(Page.ofSize(25));

// get the first page
Uni<List<Person>> firstPage = livingPersons.list();

// get the second page
Uni<List<Person>> secondPage = livingPersons.nextPage().list();

// get page 7
Uni<List<Person>> page7 = livingPersons.page(Page.of(7, 25)).list();

// get the number of pages
Uni<Integer> numberOfPages = livingPersons.pageCount();

// get the total number of entities returned by this query without paging
Uni<Long> count = livingPersons.count();

// and you can chain methods of course
Uni<List<Person>> persons = Person.find("status", Status.Alive)
        .page(Page.ofSize(25))
        .nextPage()
        .list();
```

> I'm getting a well known error because of "HR000068: This method should exclusively be invoked from a Vert.x EventLoop thread".

This seems a bit unrelated to your original question. We cannot help without seeing some code or having a test case. It could be a bug, but usually it means one is trying to use reactive code in a block that's not reactive.

Comment: One note: page is misleading. It’s actually not the page but index !

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks for your reply. I saw the page you mentioned. My question is not related to Pagination itself. I know how to use pagination. I provide the example in this link: https://gist.github.com/serrodcal/bf70923208d0b589364850d95d27337a. Basically, I'm getting `JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState` error because I'm running two queries in the same session (my understanding). Is there a way to do what I show you in `OrderResource`?  Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot run two query in parallel with the session. So, you cannot use `.combine().all()`. You need to run one query (the count one for example) and then chain the other one

Comment: That was the other alternative I was thinking. Thanks for your help. I'll provide an answer once I got it.